# Reverse Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] array)

Tags: c#

In example

```
string newString = Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] array)
```

How would I go about converting `newString` to get a `byte[]` (byte array)?

Comment: Please rephrase your question... I'm not sure what you're asking for......

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Convert.FromBase64String(newString)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(newString);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] array= Convert.FromBase64String(newString);
```